# preferexternal in manifest not working when installing from market

Tags: android, sd-card

The manifest of my app has the following settings

```
<manifest ... android:installLocation="preferExternal">
```

and

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

When testing on a 2.2 device the app gets installed on the external sd-card. But when I install the same app from the android market. The application gets installed on the internal card with no option to move it to the external card. So the installLocation seems to be ignored.

Is there something I missed? Or is it a bug?

**Problem solved!**

After some further searching on the net I found a little comment about setting the 'content protection' in the app market. And not allowing the app to be moved to the external sd card.

So if you turn the 'content protection' off in the app market, the app can be moved to the external card.

Comment: Shouldn't turn it on any more anyway. Content Protection is Deprecated - use Application Licensing http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html

Comment: Can you add your solution as an answer below so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thanks.

Comment: You answered my problem, I had added installLocation under the uses-sdk tags :(

Comment: any solution in 2018?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested by Bill the Lizard

**Problem solved!**

After some further searching on the net I found a little comment about setting the 'content protection' in the app market. And not allowing the app to be moved to the external sd card.

So if you turn the 'content protection' off in the app market, the app can be moved to the external card.